# Find Object with Property in Array

Tags: ios, swift

is there a possibility to get an object from an array with an specific property? Or do i need to loop trough all objects in my array and check if an property is the specific i was looking for?

edit: Thanks for given me into the correct direction, but i have a problem to convert this.

// edit again: A ok, and if there is only one specific result? Is this also a possible method do to that?

```
let imageUUID = sender.imageUUID


let questionImageObjects = self.formImages[currentSelectedQuestion.qIndex] as [Images]!

    // this is working
    //var imageObject:Images!
    /*
    for (index, image) in enumerate(questionImageObjects) {

        if(image.imageUUID == imageUUID) {
            imageObject = image
        }

    }
    */

// this is not working - NSArray is not a subtype of Images- so what if there is only 1 possible result?
var imageObject = questionImageObjects.filter( { return $0.imageUUID == imageUUID } )
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

> // this is not working - NSArray is not a subtype of Images- so what if there is only 1 possible result?

You have no way to prove at compile-time that there is only one possible result on an array. What you're actually asking for is the *first* matching result. The easiest (though not the fastest) is to just take the first element of the result of filter:

```
let imageObject = questionImageObjects.filter{ $0.imageUUID == imageUUID }.first
```

`imageObject` will now be an optional of course, since it's possible that nothing matches.

If searching the whole array is time consuming, of course you can easily create a `firstMatching` function that will return the (optional) first element matching the closure, but for short arrays this is fine and simple.

---

As charles notes, in Swift 3 this is built in:

```
questionImageObjects.first(where: { $0.imageUUID == imageUUID })
```

Comment: You could add the `lazy` function in the middle, so it should only scan the array up to the first match, and avoid the performance issue you rightly mention: `let imageObject = questionImageObjects.lazy.filter{ $0.imageUUID == imageUUID }.first`

Comment: Actually, `questionImageObjects.first(where: { $0.imageUUID == imageUUID })` is probably the way to go with swift 3

Answer (score 32):

**Edit 2016-05-05:** Swift 3 will include [`first(where:)`](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-May/000134.html).

In Swift 2, you can use `indexOf` to find the index of the first array element that matches a predicate.

```
let index = questionImageObjects.indexOf({$0.imageUUID == imageUUID})
```

This is bit faster compared to `filter` since it will stop after the first match. (Alternatively, you could use a `lazy` sequence.)

However, it's a bit annoying that you can only get the index and not the object itself. I use the following extension for convenience:

```
extension CollectionType {
    func find(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Generator.Element? {
        return try indexOf(predicate).map({self[$0]})
    }
}
```

Then the following works:

```
questionImageObjects.find({$0.imageUUID == imageUUID})
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use the `filter` method which takes a closure where you can set your logical expression.

Example:

```
struct User {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
}

let users = [User(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"), User(firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Clinton"), User(firstName: "John", lastName: "Travolta")];

let johns = users.filter( { return $0.firstName == "John" } )
```

Note that `filter` returns an array containing all items satisfying the logical expression.

More info in the [Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW46)

Comment: You can also use NSPredicate and use an NSarray.

Comment: How to filter on firstName and lastName?

Comment: @Kaptain: That should be pretty simple: replace `return $0.firstName == "John"` with `return $0.firstName == "John" && $0.lastName == "Doe"`. In other words, simply rewrite/extend the closure passed to the filter, determining when an element should be included or not

Answer (score 11):

Here is a working example in **Swift 5**

```
class Point{
    var x:Int
    var y:Int
    
    init(x:Int, y:Int){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

var p1 = Point(x:1, y:2)
var p2 = Point(x:2, y:3)
var p3 = Point(x:1, y:4)
var points = [p1, p2, p3]

// Find the first object with given property
// In this case, firstMatchingPoint becomes p1
let firstMatchingPoint = points.first{$0.x == 1}

// Find all objects with given property
// In this case, allMatchingPoints becomes [p1, p3]
let allMatchingPoints = points.filter{$0.x == 1}
```

**Reference:**
[Trailing Closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)

Answer (score 3):

Here is other way to fetch particular object by using object property to search an object in array.

```
if arrayTicketsListing.contains({ $0.status_id == "2" }) {
      let ticketStatusObj: TicketsStatusList = arrayTicketsListing[arrayTicketsListing.indexOf({ $0.status_id == "2" })!]
      print(ticketStatusObj.status_name)
}
```

Whereas, my arrayTicketsListing is `[TicketsStatusList]` contains objects of `TicketsStatusList` class.

```
// TicketsStatusList class

class TicketsStatusList {
    internal var status_id: String
    internal var status_name: String
    init(){
        status_id = ""
        status_name = ""
    }
}
```