# Find an object in array?

Tags: ios, swift

Does Swift have something like [_.findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) in Underscore.js?

I have an array of structs of type `T` and would like to check if array contains a struct object whose `name` property is equal to `Foo`.

Tried to use `find()` and `filter()` but they only work with primitive types, e.g. `String` or `Int`. Throws an error about not conforming to `Equitable` protocol or something like that.

Comment: This could be what you are looking for: [Find Object with Property in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073331/find-object-with-property-in-array).

Comment: why not convert to nsdictionary and search for

Comment: I believe find is no longer available in Swift 2.0.. I was converting some 1.2 code to Swift 2.0 and it said to use IndexOf instead.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

FWIW, if you don't want to use custom function or extension, you can:

```
let array = [ .... ]
if let found = find(array.map({ $0.name }), "Foo") {
    let obj = array[found]
}
```

This generates `name` array first, then `find` from it.

If you have huge array, you might want to do:

```
if let found = find(lazy(array).map({ $0.name }), "Foo") {
    let obj = array[found]
}
```

or maybe:

```
if let found = find(lazy(array).map({ $0.name == "Foo" }), true) {
    let obj = array[found]
}
```

Comment: This is even better. I will mark this as answer since it looks simpler overall and it does not require creating a custom function.

Comment: As of Swift 2.0 you can use:
array.indexOf({$0.name == "Foo"})

Comment: As of Swift 3.0 you can use: array.first(where:{$0.name == "Foo"}) if you need the object

Comment: How can I check $0.name contains string "foo"? answers are about exact matching. I need contains string. Can anyone give the syntax for that

Answer (score 420):

**SWIFT 5**

**Check if the element exists**

```
if array.contains(where: {$0.name == "foo"}) {
   // it exists, do something
} else {
   //item could not be found
}
```

**Get the element**

```
if let foo = array.first(where: {$0.name == "foo"}) {
   // do something with foo
} else {
   // item could not be found
}
```

**Get the element and its offset**

```
if let foo = array.enumerated().first(where: {$0.element.name == "foo"}) {
   // do something with foo.offset and foo.element
} else {
   // item could not be found
}
```

**Get the offset**

```
if let fooOffset = array.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == "foo"}) {
    // do something with fooOffset
} else {
    // item could not be found
}
```

Comment: Nice Swift-style answer!

Comment: Thanks you are my saver this has cleaned my code a lot

Comment: how to check multiple conditions say i need to check if the array  `$0.name == "foo"` do one operation and  `$0.name == "boo"`  do another operation

Comment: This helped me more than the accepted answer in 2020.

Comment: How can I check $0.name contains string "foo"? Can anyone give the syntax for that

Comment: use `$0.name.contains("foo")` instead of `$0.name == "foo"`

Comment: array.first() is really helped in most of the cases.

Comment: The object that is returned by the `array.enumerated().first` according to apple is an `EnumeratedSequence` -- is there a shorter, more colloquial term anyone finds useful, I guess tuple would be a good candidate? Purely for variable naming when using this strategy, thanks!

Answer (score 161):

You can use the `index` method available on `Array` with a predicate ([see Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index)).

```
func index(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int?
```

For your specific example this would be:

**Swift 5.0**

```
if let i = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Foo" }) {
    return array[i]
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
if let i = array.index(where: { $0.name == Foo }) {
    return array[i]
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
if let i = array.indexOf({ $0.name == Foo }) {
    return array[i]
}
```

Comment: Yes this works with swift 2.0 only. Sorry should have mentioned it .

Comment: @user3799504 meanning of $0 ?

Comment: $0 is shorthand for the first argument to the closure. In this case it refers to self.generator.element or each element of the array.  Please see : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: How about Swift 3?

Answer (score 42):

**Swift 3**

If you need the object use:

```
array.first{$0.name == "Foo"}
```

(If you have more than one object named "Foo" then `first` will return the first object from an unspecified ordering)

Comment: Thank you for this. This should be way up there!

Comment: This is nice, thank you!
Can be written like this also:
`array.first {$0.name == "Foo"}`

Comment: In **Swift3** it must be `array.first(where: {$0.name == "Foo"})`

Comment: With Daniel's note, this is THE correct, best answer for Swift 3. Don't use map, filter for this purpose; they iterate over entire collections, which can be hugely wasteful.

Answer (score 24):

You can *filter* the array and then just pick the first element, as shown
in [Find Object with Property in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073331/find-object-with-property-in-array).

Or you define a custom extension

```
extension Array {

    // Returns the first element satisfying the predicate, or `nil`
    // if there is no matching element.
    func findFirstMatching<L : BooleanType>(predicate: T -> L) -> T? {
        for item in self {
            if predicate(item) {
                return item // found
            }
        }
        return nil // not found
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct T {
    var name : String
}

let array = [T(name: "bar"), T(name: "baz"), T(name: "foo")]

if let item = array.findFirstMatching( { $0.name == "foo" } ) {
    // item is the first matching array element
} else {
    // not found
}
```

---

In **Swift 3** you can use the existing `first(where:)` method
(as [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/find-an-object-in-array/28728700?noredirect=1#comment66831811_28733586)):

```
if let item = array.first(where: { $0.name == "foo" }) {
    // item is the first matching array element
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: In terms of efficiency how does this compare with `array.lazy.filter( predicate ).first` ?  How efficient is .lazy for small arrays?

Comment: @PatNiemeyer: I don't know, you would have to measure the performance and compare.

Comment: @PatNiemeyer the solution above will most certainly be more efficient even though the difference won't be probably big. 1. Complexity of the `filter` is always `O(n)` whereas in the `findFirstMatching` it's only in the worst scenario (when the element you are looking for is the last or not in the array at all). 2. `filter` creates a completely new array of filtered elements while  the `findFirstMatching` just returns the requested element.

Comment: In Swift 3, I'm getting the errors _Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Bool'_ and _Use of undeclared type 'T'_ for this extension method.

Comment: @Isuru: That answer was quite old and referred to an old Swift version. In Swift 3 you don't need an custom extension method anymore for that purpose, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 3.0**

```
if let index = array.index(where: { $0.name == "Foo" }) {
    return array[index]
}
```

**Swift 2.1**

Filtering in object properties is now supported in swift 2.1. You can filter your array based on any value of the struct or class here is an example

```
for myObj in myObjList where myObj.name == "foo" {
 //object with name is foo
}
```

OR

```
for myObj in myObjList where myObj.Id > 10 {
 //objects with Id is greater than 10
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4**,

Another way to achieve this
using filter function,

```
if let object = elements.filter({ $0.title == "title" }).first {
    print("found")
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**

you can use index(where:) in Swift 3

```
func index(where predicate: @noescape Element throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int?
```

example

```
if let i = theArray.index(where: {$0.name == "Foo"}) {
    return theArray[i]
}
```

Comment: Is there a method in swift 3 where you can find the indices of a sublist of array items that fulfill the condition `$0.name == "Foo"`?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2 or later**

You can combine `indexOf` and `map` to write a "find element" function in a single line.

```
let array = [T(name: "foo"), T(name: "Foo"), T(name: "FOO")]
let foundValue = array.indexOf { $0.name == "Foo" }.map { array[$0] }
print(foundValue) // Prints "T(name: "Foo")"
```

Using `filter` + `first` looks cleaner, but `filter` evaluates all the elements in the array. `indexOf` + `map` looks complicated, but the evaluation stops when the first match in the array is found. Both the approaches have pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get access to array.index(of: Any) is by declaring your object

```
import Foundation
class Model: NSObject {  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
if yourArray.contains(item) {
   //item found, do what you want
}
else{
   //item not found 
   yourArray.append(item)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `contains`:

```
var yourItem:YourType!
if contains(yourArray, item){
    yourItem = item
}
```

Or you could try what Martin pointed you at, in the comments and give `filter` another try: [Find Object with Property in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073331/find-object-with-property-in-array).

Comment: Will that only return a boolean? I need to get the object too, not just check if is in the array.

Comment: This assume `item` is of the same type as item in the array. However, all I have is just a title from `view.annotation.title`. I need to compare items in the array by this title.

Comment: Something like `if contains(yourArray, view.annotation.title) { // code goes here }`.

Comment: Martin showed you another way in the comments. Check the link he provided.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3:**

You can use Swifts built in functionality to find custom objects in an Array.

First you must make sure your custom object conforms to the: **Equatable protocol**.

```
class Person : Equatable { //<--- Add Equatable protocol
    let name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    //Add Equatable functionality:
    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.name == rhs.name)
    }
}
```

With Equatable functionality added to your object , Swift will now show you additional properties you can use on an array:

```
//create new array and populate with objects:
let p1 = Person(name: "Paul", age: 20)
let p2 = Person(name: "Mike", age: 22)
let p3 = Person(name: "Jane", age: 33)
var people = [Person]([p1,p2,p3])

//find index by object:
let index = people.index(of: p2)! //finds Index of Mike

//remove item by index:
people.remove(at: index) //removes Mike from array
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3,

```
let index = array.index(where: {$0.name == "foo"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dollar](https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar) which is Lo-Dash or Underscore.js for Swift:

```
import Dollar

let found = $.find(array) { $0.name == "Foo" }
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if we had an array of numbers:

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

We could find the first odd number like this:

```
let firstOdd = numbers.index { $0 % 2 == 1 }
```

That will send back 4 as an optional integer, because the first odd number (9) is at index four.