# How to specify which cells to show in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, uitableview

Currently I have UITableView which shows contact list (names/phone numbers/images) and I have phone number list from server.
I need that UITableView would only show contacts that match with phone number from server. 
Contacts are imported using Contact Framework:

```
func findContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),
        CNContactImageDataKey,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)

    do {
        try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in
            //Saves all contacts as [CNContact]
            self.contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
```

And for example I get phone numbers

```
var numberArray = [String]()
var number = contacts[indexPath.row].phoneNumbers
let phoneNumber = number.value as! CNPhoneNumber
numberArray.append(phoneNumber.stringValue)
```

Is it possible to specify when tableView should return cell or should I try implementing `for _ in _` loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest` you should check to see if the phone number is in the list of phone numbers you get from the server.

Otherwise, you can filter your array of contacts using the methods presented in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28733586/1228075

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to only load the addresses into your table view data model where the phone numbers match - so you should filter the results you get from the server before showing them in the table.