# How found and get value in an array

Tags: ios, swift, find, swift3

```
let firstArray = 
[[name: "John", id: "001", active: "true"],
[name: "Paul", id: "002", active: "false"]]

let user: User? //This user contains information like an id (002)
```

hello there, i want to tell "look in the firstArray in each profil, and found the profil where the id is the same. In the example it's Paul. I want to get back the paul profil [name: "Paul", id: "002", active: "false"]

I hope this more clean now, thanks for feedback

Comment: Your actual question is unclear to me, please improve your question. The `$.find` what you named is jQuery code, not swift.

Comment: Hello, tell me if it's more clean now. $.find is a cocoapod named Dollar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an object in array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/find-an-object-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in firstArray{
    let user_id=item.value(forKey: "id") as! String
    if user_id==some_id{
        print("found user")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a second (alternative) answer or should it be an edit to you first answer?

Comment: This is another alternative. In this answer you don't have to change the structure you use. I added it when you edited your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class for your users, like:

```
class user{
    var user_id:String
    var name:String

    init(user_id:String, name:String){
        self.user_id=user_id
        self.name=name
    }
}
```

Then, create an array to store them:

```
let user_array=[user1, user2]
```

And when you need to compare users:

```
let user1=user_array[0]
if user1.id==some_id{
    //then...
}
```