# Using a JSON array from a URL and returning rows that match a value in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

I might be missing something (new to this) but I am using this [Swift 3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/find-an-object-in-array) on how to find an object in a `NSArray.`

Specifically, I want to return values from a JSON array that match a property called 'episode' (these are strings):

```
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/example.json")
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

                let json: Any?
                do{
                    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                }
                catch{
                    return
                }

                guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else {
                    return
                }

                if let foo = data_list.first(where: {$0.episode = "Example 1A"}) {
                    // do something with foo
                    print(foo)
                } else {
                    // item could not be found
                }

            }).resume()
```

Even after following XCode and using `AnyObject` (first used `Any`), it says that `Value of type 'Any' has no member 'episode'`.

My belief is this is because I am pulling this from a URL and so it doesn't know `episode` is a real member. The array I am using looks like this:

[{"show": "Example", "episode": "Episode 1A", "date":"January 23"},{"show": "Example 2", "episode": "Episode 2B", "date":"December 20"}

Any ideas what the appropriate way to return rows that match the `episode` string I specify, like "Episode 1A"?

Comment: Note that if you move up to Swift4 you could use the `Codable` protocol and serialize/deserialize your custom objects much more simply.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json` is an array of dictionary with a key of `"episode"`.

Don't use `NSArray` in Swift.

Update your code as follows:

```
guard let data_list = json as? [[String:Any]] else {
    return
}

if let foo = data_list.first(where: {$0["episode"] as? String == "Example 1A"}) {
    // do something with foo
    print(foo)
} else {
    // item could not be found
}
```

Note the two changes: the cast and the way to access the "episode". Also note the use of `==` for equality.

Comment: Actually the array is `[[String:String]]`

Comment: This works for me! Thank you for the very clear answer, and I learned something.

Comment: @vadian I considered that but wasn't 100% sure. That would be a good change if it turns out to be true.