# how to set up a search with an "if" statement for arrays, very basic app (swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm working on a basic app which has a listArray with ~1400 items, each with 3 properties (**icao**, **callsign**, image). It has 2 outlets: a "textField" and a "label". With my custom keyboard(buttons) i can write 3 characters into my "textField". And if these 3 characters are matching with the **icao** item of my listArray, then I would like the **callsign** item to be shown in my "label". Is there a way to do it with an "if" statement? I would like to see "AMERICAN" in the "label". Here is what I have:
[my xcode and simulator screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urEuU.jpg)

```
  @IBOutlet var ICAOtextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var callsignTextLabel: UILabel!

var updatedICAOtextField = ""
var listArray = [list]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpList()
}

private func setUpList() {

listArray.append(list(icao: "AAB", callsign: "A-B-G", image: "BELGIUM"))
listArray.append(list(icao: "AAC", callsign: "ARMYAIR", image: "UK"))
listArray.append(list(icao: "AAF", callsign: "AZUR", image: "FRANCE"))
listArray.append(list(icao: "AAL", callsign: "AMERICAN", image: "USA"))
}

@IBAction func abcButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    updatedICAOtextField = ICAOtextField.text! + sender.currentTitle!
    ICAOtextField.text = updatedICAOtextField
    
    if updatedICAOtextField.count > 3 {
        ICAOtextField.text = ""
    }
    
    if ICAOtextField.text ==                           {
        
        callsignTextLabel.text = "            "
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an object in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/find-an-object-in-array). Please do some research before posting, as for the linked question I would recommend to look at all the answers with a lot of votes and not only the accepted one to see different solutions to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IBAction func abcButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    updatedICAOtextField = ICAOtextField.text! + (sender.titleLabel?.text)!
    ICAOtextField.text = updatedICAOtextField
    
    if updatedICAOtextField.count >= 3 {
        let index = listArray.firstIndex { (list) -> Bool in
            if list.icao == updatedICAOtextField {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        if index != nil {
            callsignTextLabel.text = listArray[index!].callsign
        }
        ICAOtextField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, your first step UITextFieldDelegate was already added, I did the rest. App runs, no errors, but unfortunately nothing happens. With this line of code I can check wether this 3-letter-icaocode are in the array or not : 
if array.contains(where: {$0.icao == "ICAOtextField.text"}) {
   // it exists, do something    print("found")
} else {
   //item could not be found     print("not found")
}

Comment: It's little strange because it works perfectly fine on my side! Can you show me your updated code?

Comment: Please remove quotation marks! if array.contains(where: {$0.icao == ICAOtextField.text}) { // it exists, do something print("found") } else { //item could not be found print("not found") }

Comment: i removed them when i run the app, i just copied here with those marks, sorry. I also posted the whole code, for me doesn't run

Comment: Okay. Did you want this on button click? Because my func is changing callsignTextLabel label at run time, also please make sure that you are typing in upper case like AAL!

Comment: on my custom keyboard there is no "ok" nor "search" button, just the a-z buttons, and a clear button. So I want this search to be done as soon I typed the 3rd character. all typing  are uppercase.

Comment: So if I am not wrong then this whole keyboard is connected to abc button outlet right?

Comment: yes, except the clear button, it has its own

Comment: Please see updated solution. And let me know if it works

Comment: thanks man, works exactly the way I wanted

Comment: No Problem man. I'm glad this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var ICAOtextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var callsignTextLabel: UILabel!

var updatedICAOtextField = ""
var listArray = [list]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    ICAOtextField.delegate = self
    ICAOtextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    
    setUpList()
}



@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
     if ICAOtextField.text!.count >= 3 {
         let index = listArray.firstIndex { (list) -> Bool in
            if "\(list.icao)" == ICAOtextField.text {
                 return true
             }
             return false
         }
         if index != nil {
            callsignTextLabel.text = listArray[index!].callsign
         }
     }
}



private func setUpList() {

listArray.append(list(icao: "AAB", callsign: "A-B-G", image: "BELGIUM"))
listArray.append(list(icao: "AAC", callsign: "ARMYAIR", image: "UK"))
listArray.append(list(icao: "AAF", callsign: "AZUR", image: "FRANCE"))
listArray.append(list(icao: "AAL", callsign: "AMERICAN", image: "USA"))
}

@IBAction func abcButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    updatedICAOtextField = ICAOtextField.text! + sender.currentTitle!
    ICAOtextField.text = updatedICAOtextField
    
    if updatedICAOtextField.count > 3 {
        ICAOtextField.text = ""
    }
}

@IBAction func clearButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ICAOtextField.text = ""
    callsignTextLabel.text = ""
}
```

}

class list {

```
let icao: String
let callsign: String
let image: String

init(icao: String, callsign: String, image: String) {
    
    self.icao = icao
    self.callsign = callsign
    self.image = image
}
```

}