# How to create Set Extension to find unique object in the set with property?

Tags: swift, set

Have looked at a couple of solutions to find the first element in an Array where the field in a struct matches, here:
[Find object with property in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073331/find-object-with-property-in-array) and here: [find object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/find-an-object-in-array)

Adapted to only return a match if a single unique match:

```
    var foundAction: SequenceAction?
    let filteredActions = currentStatus.seqActionsList.filter({$0.verb == actionCommand})
    if filteredActions.count == 1
    {
        foundAction = filteredActions.first
    }
```

Keep using this snippet but cannot figure how to add as an extension to Set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, eventually figured it out:

```
extension Set{
func findUniqueMatch(predicate: Element -> Bool) -> Element?
{
    let filteredList = self.filter(predicate)
    if filteredList.count == 1
    {
        return filteredList.first
    }

    return nil
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets already have an `indexOf` method that lets you search for a member with a predicate. You could use that:

```
let numberSet: Set = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13]
if let index = numberSet.indexOf({ $0 % 2 == 1 }) {
    print(numberSet[index])
} else {
    print("No odd members found")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I extended Set