# Class instance reference from property

Tags: swift, class, properties

I have a class with an annotation as a property

```
class UserClass {
   var id : String?
   var annot : MKPointAnnotation?
}
```

Then I make several instances of this class like:

```
var user1 = UserClass()
```

and then define, create and add each user's annotation on the map.

Later in the code user taps on an annotation and I need a reference to the corresponding user instance. How do I get it?

```
@objc(mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let annot = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
        let user = // Need the user instance here to acces user id etc
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that a tap on an annotation corresponds to a certain user?

Comment: because i am creating one annotation for each user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Object with Property in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073331/find-object-with-property-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have all the users in an array in the class you are populating the map view with the annotations. If not, have all the users stored in an array and then:

```
@objc(mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   if let annot = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
      let user = usersArray.first(where:{$0.annot == annot})
   }
}
```